# Chromium Crashes When Triggering File Dialog

Tags: snap, chromium

I've installed Chromium via Snap. Chromium seems to crash any time it triggers a native file dialog. This can be replicated by doing "Save file as", "Save image as" or simply doing CTRL+O to open a local web page.

I've launched it from the terminal to see if it has any prints. Here's what I've got *before* the crash:

```
/home/erayerdin/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/erayerdin/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so
/home/erayerdin/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/erayerdin/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
/home/erayerdin/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/erayerdin/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
/home/erayerdin/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/erayerdin/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so
Gtk-Message: 08:07:49.139: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

(chrome:6811): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:07:52.019: /snap/chromium/1514/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(chrome:6811): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:07:52.019: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(chrome:6811): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:07:57.896: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
```

Here's what I've got *when* it crashed:

```
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/chromium/1506/data-dir/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unable to load image-loading module: /snap/chromium/1514/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: /snap/chromium/1514/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 5)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is the issue here? How can I resolve this?

---

## Environment

- Kubuntu 20.04.2
- Chromium 89.0.4389.72 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

Comment: Seems like `image-missing.png` is missing and since Chromium is in a *confined* environment and *they manage the dependencies*, the issue cannot seem to be resolved. At least this is what I understood from the error message.

Comment: Just [reported a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1918578) to its related launchpad domain. Mods can close the question if they find it suitable.

Comment: I'll suggest filing using `ubuntu-bug` in future.. it provides more detail about your system, release, packages etc.  (FYI:  I'm here because of your askubu post on the bug report), but Thank You for taking the time to report this bug, and helping make Ubuntu better!